# Exporting 8million records from Oracle to MongoDB

Tags: oracle, mongodb, export, database

Now I have an Oracle Database with 8 millions records and I need to move them to MongoDB.
I know how to import some data to MongoDB with JSON file using import command but I want to know that is there a better way to achieve this regarding these issues.

- Due to the limit of execution time, how to handle it?
- The database is going up every seconds so what's the plan to make sure that every records have been moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Due to the limit of execution time, how to handle it?

Don't do it with the JSON export / import. Instead you should write a script that reads the data, transforms into the correct format for MongoDB and then inserts it there.

There are a few reasons for this:

- Your tables / collections will not be organized the same way. (*If they are, then why are you using MongoDB?*)
- This will allow you to monitor progress of the operation. In particular you can output to log files every 1000th entry or so to get some progress and be able to recover from failures.
- This will test your new MongoDB code.

> The database is going up every seconds so what's the plan to make sure that every records have been moved.

There are two strategies here.

1. Track the entries that are updated and re-run your script on newly updated records until you are caught up.
2. Write to both databases while you run the script to copy data. Then once you've done the script and everything it up to date, you can cut over to just using MongoDB.

I personally suggest #2, this is the easiest method to manage and test while maintaining up-time. It's still going to be a lot of work, but this will allow the transition to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I forgot to tell that I used Codeigniter PHP Framework.

Comment: No problem. The best way to thank me for the answer is to mark my reply as the correct answer and to give it an upvote.

Comment: Now I write a script that reads the data from Oracle and use the MongoDB class to insert the results I've read into MongoDB. I also set the limit of records for each execution. Is this the way you suggested me?